# The DELETE method is not supported. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST. What i do now?

Tags: laravel, destroy

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('product.destroy',['product' => $product->id])}}">
                              @method('DELETE')
                              @csrf
                              <button type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger">Trashed</button>
                            </form>



public function destroy(Product $product)
{
    $product->delete();
    // Product::findOrFail($request->id)->delete();
    return back()->with('success','Product Trashed Successfully');
}
```

Web.php

Route::resource('product', ProductController::class);

[The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.]

Comment: Your `<form>` method is `post` .. ( `<form method="POST" action="` ) Could this be conflicting with your `@method('DELETE')` ?

Comment: try clearing caches `php artisan route:clear && php artisan view:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan clear-compiled && composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more review, I think Laravel is looking for /products/   and the singular to be product.   You are using singular and singular.   Try

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('products.destroy',['product' => $product->id])}}">
                              @method('DELETE')
                              @csrf
                              <button type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger">Trashed</button>
                            </form>



public function destroy(Product $product)
{
    $product->delete();
    // Product::findOrFail($request->id)->delete();
    return back()->with('success','Product Trashed Successfully');
}

Route::resource('products', ProductController::class);
```

Otherwise, you may have to scope the singular product to product because you are not following the naming convention it is expecting.

```
Route::resource('products', ProductController::class)->scoped([
    'product' => 'product',
]);
```

Comment: reference https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller  and https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers.  I may be wrong but what does a php artisan route:list show you for product?